# How can I manually instantiate a controller's attribute based route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am implementing a web API that will return a 202 Accepted to the client when a resource is not yet available. The URL returned to the client would look something like

`http://host/api/v2/**thing**reqests/*guid*`

I want to do this generically as I have many different types of resources (and hence controllers) and I do not want to duplicate code.

I created

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class RelatedControllerAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type RelatedControllerType { get; }

    public RelatedControllerAttribute(Type relatedControllerType) => RelatedControllerType = relatedControllerType;
}
```

and applied it to the main controller like so

```
[RelatedController(typeof(ThingRequestsController))]
public class ThingsController : ApiController<ThingRequest>
```

This allows me to get to the route template associated with the requests controller.

```
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
```

with this code in a base class of the ThingsController

```
    private string GetRequestsRoute()
    {
        if (_requestsPath != null)
            return _requestsPath;

        var a = GetType().GetCustomAttribute<RelatedControllerAttribute>();
        if (a == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        var routeTemplate = a.RelatedControllerType.GetCustomAttribute<RouteAttribute>().RouteTemplate;

        return _requestsPath = route.Name;
    }
```

This gets me almost all the way there. How do I instantiate the route template with the correct meaningful values. Is there something built into ASP.NET Core? I can easily do the `[controller]` part of the route, but how do I do the `{version:ApiVersion}` part (that comes from the ApiExplorer)?

Comment: I believe you are looking for the [UrlHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.urlhelper?view=aspnetcore-2.1).  You can determine the route (if you have multiple) by using [DataTokens](https://andrewlock.net/using-routing-datatokens-in-asp-net-core/) or if you only have one route, give it a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this. It feels a bit sub-optimal, but it works.

```
    private string GetRequestsRoute(string requestsRoot)
    {
        if (_requestsPath != null)
            return _requestsPath;

        var relatedControllerAttribute = GetType().GetCustomAttribute<RelatedControllerAttribute>();
        if (relatedControllerAttribute  == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException($"The {GetType().Name} must have a ${typeof(RelatedControllerAttribute).Name}");

        var apiExplorerSettingsAttribute = relatedControllerAttribute.RelatedControllerType.GetCustomAttribute<ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute>();
        if (apiExplorerSettingsAttribute == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException($"The {relatedControllerAttribute.RelatedControllerType.Name} must have a ${typeof(ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute).Name}");

        var routeAttribute = relatedControllerAttribute.RelatedControllerType.GetCustomAttribute<RouteAttribute>();
        if (routeAttribute == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException($"The {relatedControllerAttribute.RelatedControllerType.Name} must have a ${typeof(RouteAttribute).Name}");

        return _requestsPath = routeAttribute.Template
            .Replace(
                "[controller]",
                relatedControllerAttribute.RelatedControllerType.Name.Replace("Controller", ""))
            .Replace(
                "{version:apiVersion}",
                apiExplorerSettingsAttribute.GroupName.Replace("v", ""))
            .ToLowerInvariant();
    }
```